# Android Camera API App force closes on button click in Jelly Bean

Tags: android, camera, forceclose

Following code runs perfectly on ice cream sandwich but it force closes on Jelly Bean and Kitkat.
Please help me with it.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.final_cam;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
final static String DEBUG_TAG = "MainActivity";
  private Camera camera;
  private int cameraId = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     // do we have a camera?
    if (!getPackageManager()
        .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "No camera on this device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
          .show();
    } else {
      cameraId = findFrontFacingCamera();
      if (cameraId < 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No front facing camera found.",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      } else {
        camera = Camera.open(cameraId);
      }
    }
}

 public void onClick(View view) {
        camera.takePicture(null, null,
            new PhotoHandler(getApplicationContext()));
      }
  private int findFrontFacingCamera() {
        int cameraId = -1;
        // Search for the front facing camera
        int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
          CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
          Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
          if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Camera found");
            cameraId = i;
            break;
          }
        }
        return cameraId;
      }
  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    if (camera != null) {
      camera.release();
      camera = null;
    }
    super.onPause();
  }
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

PhotoHandler.java

```
package com.example.final_cam;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PhotoHandler implements PictureCallback {
private final Context context;
 public PhotoHandler(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
      }
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    File pictureFileDir = getDir();

    if (!pictureFileDir.exists() && !pictureFileDir.mkdirs()) {

      Log.d(MainActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "Can't create directory to save image.");
      Toast.makeText(context, "Can't create directory to save image.",
          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      return;       
}
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddhhmmss");
    String date = dateFormat.format(new Date());
    String photoFile = "Picture_" + date + ".jpg";

    String filename = pictureFileDir.getPath() + File.separator + photoFile;

    File pictureFile = new File(filename);  

try {
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
      fos.write(data);
      fos.close();
      Toast.makeText(context, "New Image saved:" + photoFile,
          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception error) {
      Log.d(MainActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "File" + filename + "not saved: "
          + error.getMessage());
      Toast.makeText(context, "Image could not be saved.",
          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

 private File getDir() {
        File sdDir = Environment
          .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        return new File(sdDir, "CameraAPIDemo");
      }
    }
```

I used the code given in the link here...
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCamera/article.html
It ran successfully in my Galaxy Tab (Ice Cream Sandwich) but force closes as i click on Make Photo button in case of Jelly Bean and Kitkat. Please guide me where it is wrong.. and what all changes to be made..??

Answer (score 1):

You should post the actual error you're seeing in the logs (exception/stack trace).

However, it looks like you never start camera preview. While it may work on some manufacturer's devices, you are required to start up camera preview before you can take a picture.  This means you need a target for your preview (either a SurfaceView or a SurfaceTexture), and you need to start preview once your Surface has become valid.

Please take a look at the sample camera app at the Android developer website for details:
[Building a camera app](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera)